# airflow.exceptions.DuplicateTaskIdFound exception

Tags: python, airflow

Hi I need to define a DAG with a task and the task has to be invoked 4 times every day. But when I publish to DAG, I got an airflow.exceptions.DuplicationTaskIdFound error, see my DAG definition below:

```
import sys
import time
from airflow.models import DAG,Variable
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.ssh.hooks.ssh import SSHHook
from airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh import SSHOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.external_task import ExternalTaskMarker, ExternalTaskSensor
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
import pendulum
sys.path.append("../..")
from common.airflow_dep_coordinator import airfow_coordinator
from common import airflow_utli
from common import airflow_config

default_args = airflow_utli.default_args
default_args['owner'] = 'bi'
default_args['sla'] = timedelta(hours=6)
default_args['retries'] = 3
default_args['start_date'] = datetime(2022,4,29, tzinfo=airflow_utli.local_tz) #TODO please override start date of this dag

airflow_config.EMAIL_RECIEVER_LIST=Variable.get("bi_email_reciever_list",deserialize_json=True , default_var=None)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Get data string
# @beforeOfDay, the day before current day
# @with_dash, whether the result string contains dash, default False
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def getdate(beforeOfDay, with_dash=False):
        today = datetime.now()
        offset = timedelta(days=-beforeOfDay)
        str_date_format ='%Y%m%d'
        if(with_dash):
            str_date_format ='%Y-%m-%d'
        date_str = (today + offset).strftime(str_date_format)
        return date_str

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Get etl task, return SSHOperator
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def batch_etl_task(dag,target_table_name, param=None,ssh_conn_id=SSHHOOK_NAME):
    sh_command =  COMMAND_BASE+ COMMAND.format(target_table_name=target_table_name, param=param)
    print(sh_command)
    task = SSHOperator(
        dag=dag, task_id=target_table_name, ssh_conn_id=ssh_conn_id, command=sh_command
    )
    return task

# =========================================================================
# DAG definition
# =========================================================================
dag=DAG(
    dag_id='lakehouse_dws_otp_app_user_daily', 
    default_args=default_args,
    tags=['bi','dws','otp','app'], 
    schedule_interval='00 04 * * *', 
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=6),
    concurrency=12,
    catchup=False,
    params={"pday": getdate(2),"fday":getdate(1),
            "pdaym1": getdate(3),"fdaym1":getdate(2),
            "pdaym7": getdate(9),"fdaym7":getdate(8),
            "pdaym30": getdate(32),"fdaym30":getdate(31)
           },
    sla_miss_callback=airflow_utli.default_sla_callback
)

#etl task
task_dws_fact_com_otp_app_visitor_snp_t=batch_etl_task(dag=dag,target_table_name='AnotherTargetTable',param='{{ params.pday }} {{params.fday}}')

task_dws_fact_com_otp_app_active_retention_snp_t=batch_etl_task(dag=dag,target_table_name='target_table',param='{{ params.pday }} {{params.fday}}')
task_dws_fact_com_otp_app_active_retention_snp_t_m1=batch_etl_task(dag=dag,target_table_name='target_table',param='{{ params.pdaym1 }} {{params.fdaym1}}')
task_dws_fact_com_otp_app_active_retention_snp_t_m7=batch_etl_task(dag=dag,target_table_name='target_table',param='{{ params.pdaym7 }} {{params.fdaym7}}')
task_dws_fact_com_otp_app_active_retention_snp_t_m30=batch_etl_task(dag=dag,target_table_name='target_table',param='{{ params.pdaym30 }} {{params.fdaym30}}')

### End
end_dws_otp_register_daily=DummyOperator(
task_id='end_dws_otp_register_daily',
dag=dag)

### Dependence, TODO please setup the dependency tree
[task_dws_fact_com_otp_app_new_visitor_t,task_dws_fact_com_otp_app_active_au_snp_t]>>task_dws_fact_com_otp_app_active_retention_snp_t>>task_dws_fact_com_otp_app_active_retention_snp_t_m1
```

as you can see,  I need to invoke etl to update target_table 4 times with different parameters, but this is not work seems DAG doesn't allow me to define task 4 times with same target table, so is there any best practice to achive this purpose in one DAG?

Comment: Please paste the full errortrace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have implemented `batch_etl_task` to set the `task_id` for the `SSHOperator` to the name of the `target_table_name`.

You must pass unique names for the `task_id` to register a `DagNode`.